# Try to remove only character in first line from read text File

Tags: c, cvi

[C Platform]
i have a text file and first line of the text file as "Calibrate     (version 6.0.26.54947)"
i need to ignore the characters "Calibrate     (version           )" and read only the number "6.0.26.54947".

i have following code and struck to continue.. could any one help me.

```
// open a file
pFile = fopen("text.txt", "r" );
if ( pFile == NULL ) {
    WriteToErrorWin("ERROR: Can not open the file!");
    return ( -1 );
}

// get a file size
fseek(pFile, 0 , SEEK_END);
lFileSize = ftell(pFile); 
rewind(pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
szFile = (char*)calloc(lFileSize, sizeof(char));
if ( szFile == NULL ) {
    fclose(pFile);
    return ( -1 );
}

char *szFileLine_1 = szFile;   
if( fgets(szFileLine_1, lFileSize , pFile) == NULL ){
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You're asking how to extract `"6.0.26.54947"` from the string `"Calibrate (version 6.0.26.54947)"`. So why do you post all that irrelevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you can try:

```
  char *text = "Calibrate (version 6.0.26.54947)";

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
    if (text[i] >= 46 && text[i] <= 57) {
      printf("%c", text[i]);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
```

Based on the ASCII table:

[image]

Output:

```
6.0.26.54947
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fseek()` and `ftell` to get the file size is not advisable, instead you should use `fstat()`

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;    // setup fp

    struct stat statbuf;
    fstat(fileno(fp), &statbuf);

    long file_size = statbuf.st_size;
}
```

Use can use a function like this to read the characters you are interested in

```
char* read_version(char* line, char* allow) // allow = "0123456789."
{
    char* re_result = malloc(strlen(line) + 1); // prepare for the edge case
    char* result = re_result;
    char tmp[2]; tmp[1] = '\0';
    for (; *line != '\0'; line++) {
        tmp[0] = *line;
        if (strstr(allow, tmp) != NULL) {
            *result = *line;
            result++;
        }
    }

    *result = '\0';

    return re_result;
}
```

Comment: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=87152291#content/view/87152291 Refer to this link for more details on why you shouldn't use fseek and ftell for computing file sizes.